# Fastest way to solve a in $ax^2+ bx + 1 = 0$ where there are 2 distinct roots less than 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the question:

Let $a, b$ are integers, and the equation $ax^2+ bx + 1 = 0$ has two distinct positive roots both of which are less than 1. Find the least value of $a$.

You can solve using AM-GM by making $ax^2+ bx + 1 = 0$ a function of F(x), but I am certain this is not the fastest way. Any faster solutions?

Comment: Do you mean that the roots should be _strictly_ less than $1$?

Comment: The roots are between (0,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things we can read off the expression immediately. For simplicity, set $f(x) = ax^2 - bx + 1$ (yes, I swapped a sign, it makes things cleaner below). We get

- $a>0$: as $f(0) = 1$, and we want two roots in the interval $(0,1)$
- $\frac{b}4\cdot b > 4a$: as we want $f$ to have two distinct real roots (I rewrote $b^2 - 4a > 0$ to better suit my later argument)
- $b\leq a$: as we want $f(1)>0$, which gives us $a-b+1>0$
- $0<b$: as the point of symmetry (which is $-\frac{-b}{2a}$) is positive, and $a$ is positive

Here we note that $0<b\leq a$ together with $\frac{b}4\cdot b > 4a$ means we must have $\frac{b}4 > 1$, and therefore $b>4$ and thus also $a>4$. So we try the first possible case after that, which is $a = b = 5$. And that works.

Comment: Does the swapped sign make anything different?

Comment: @chem1kal Mostly that I don't have to write $-b$ in every single one of my inequalities. $b$ signifies an arbitrary integer, and we can therefore put any sign we want in front of it, and the net effect will merely change the sign of the resulting answer. For instance, if I had kept the sign from your problem, I just would've gotten $b = -5$ instead. But the inequalities would've been uglier.